# Store result of a query inside a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, postgis

I've the following function:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
maxgid      integer;
tableloop   integer;
obstacle    geometry;
simplifyedobstacle  geometry;
BEGIN

    select max(gid) from public.terrain_obstacle_temp into maxgid;

    FOR tableloop IN 1 .. maxgid
    LOOP
        insert into public.terrain_obstacle (tse_coll,tse_height,geom) select tse_coll,tse_height,geom
        from public.terrain_obstacle_temp where gid = tableloop;

    END LOOP;

END
$do$;
```

I need to modify this function in order to execute different queries according to the type of a column of `public.terrain_obstacle_temp`.

This is a temporary table created by reading a shapefile, and I need to know the kind of the `geom` column of that table. I have a query that give the data to me:

```
SELECT type 
FROM geometry_columns 
WHERE f_table_schema = 'public' 
AND f_table_name = 'terrain_obstacle' 
and f_geometry_column = 'geom';
```

It returns me a `character_varying` value (in this case `MULTIPOLYGON`).

Ho can I modify the function in order to get the result of the query, and create an `if` statement that allows me to execute some code according to the result of that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the intention to copy all the records from the temp table to the actual table?  If so, you may be able to skip the loop:

```
insert into public.terrain_obstacle (tse_coll, tse_height, geom)
  select tse_coll, tse_height, geom
    from public.terrain_obstacle_temp
;
```

Do `terrain_obstacle` and `terrain_obstacle_temp` have the same structure?  If so, then the "insert into ... select ..." should work fine provided the column types are the same.

If conditional typing is required, use the `CASE WHEN` syntax:

```
v_type  geometry_columns.type%TYPE;

...

SELECT type
  INTO v_type 
  FROM geometry_columns 
  WHERE f_table_schema = 'public' 
    AND f_table_name = 'terrain_obstacle' 
    AND f_geometry_column = 'geom'
;

insert into public.terrain_obstacle (tse_coll, tse_height, geom)
  select tse_coll
        ,tse_height
        ,CASE WHEN v_type = 'MULTIPOLYGON' THEN my_func1(geom)
              WHEN v_type = 'POINT' THEN my_func2(geom)
              ELSE my_default(geom)
         END
    from public.terrain_obstacle_temp
;
```